# Images are different sizes in different browsers

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, progressive-web-apps

I am building an app in Ionic (for browsers to begin with). I am using firefox to test and everything looks great, but when I open the page in chrome the images are significantly smaller.

I am not sure how to go about correcting this.

I read something about resetting the css? Is this what I should be doing?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are you using `ion-img` and setting height/width like [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/) infer?

Comment: @ChrisW. That worked. But do you know how I can make the ion-img responsive so that it is smaller when the screen is small?